# Piping date into string join command in fish

Tags: shell, fish

I want to format the date command to use as a logging file name. Ideally I would like to use a command like this:

```
set dt (echo (date)) && string join '' $dt
```

When I run this I get the normal date output:

```
Tue Jun  7 22:25:26 PDT 2022
```

I want output like this:

```
TueJun722:26:09PDT2022
```

Is there a way to use a pipe command for this?

Comment: Do you want remove white spaces ? you can use sed command `echo "Tue Jun  7 22:25:26 PDT 2022" | sed 's/ //g'`

Comment: @behroozrazzaghi and if I wanted to use the command ```date``` for this?

Comment: May I suggest reconsidering that "filename"? It's next to impossible to sort that sensibly. How about ISO8601? `20220607T222526` The `date` command for that would be: `date "+%Y%m%dT%H%H%M"`

Comment: `  date '+%a %B %u  %H:%M:%S %Z %Y' | sed 's/ //g' ` return your date and remove  remove white spaces . in some situation %Z returns time difference not the region name

Comment: @behroozrazzaghi why on earth would you add the spaces to the `date` format string to then remove them with `sed`?

Comment: @tink yes it was my wrong we can remove spaces and sed `date '+%a%B%u%H:%M:%S%Z%'Y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important part here is this:

**Unlike bash, fish only splits command substitutions on newlines, not other whitespace. Spaces and tabs don't matter.**

> ```
> set dt (echo (date)) && string join '' $dt
> ```

What this does is:

- Run `date` - this prints `Tue Jun  7 22:25:26 PDT 2022`
- Split that on newlines. There's no newline (except at the end), so this ends up as one argument
- Run the equivalent of `echo 'Tue Jun  7 22:25:26 PDT 2022'` and split it on newlines (once again no newlines in the string)
- Run the equivalent of `set dt 'Tue Jun  7 22:25:26 PDT 2022'`
- This succeeded (because `echo` did, and it basically always does), so we go on
- Run the equivalent of `string join '' 'Tue Jun  7 22:25:26 PDT 2022'` - the variable was set to one argument, so it will expand to one argument (no word-splitting like in bash)
- `string join` only adds the joiner between arguments, so since there is only one argument it is printed as-is

What you want is to either

1. Remove all whitespace with `string replace`
2. Split your date on whitespace, and *then* join it

The former:

```
set dt (date | string replace -ra '\s*' '')
```

This runs `string replace` in *r*egex mode (`-r`) and tells it to replace all occurences in a line (`-a` - this is like `sed`s '/g' modifier). `string` can take its arguments either on the commandline or via a pipe, if you have an external command anyway it reads better to pipe it, and you don't have to fiddle with the `--` option separator.

The latter:

```
set dt (date | string split -n ' ' | string join '')
```

The `-n` means `string split` will skip empty entries. Note that the former removes all whitespace (including e.g. tab), while the latter only cares about actual space characters. For `date` it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Alternatively you can fiddle with date's format string. I'll leave that up to the reader.